# Is there a simple script one could you to scan QR code data and directly enter data the information into a specific column of the Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Lets see we have a simple spreadsheet that looks like this:
      TimeStamp, Name, Age, Email, QR code, Scanned Info
Row1
Row2
Row3

Then column "QR code" is generated by using the trick from here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hBMoc-FmAXf4z3LOGez8hnXg_S6rbCnCDVNzfQOhlPc/template/preview?usp=drive_web   and the QR code simply encodes the Name info per row which represents 3 different people in this case.

Now, If one were to scan these 3 QR codes, how could I extract the information of the QR codes (names in this case) and enter it under the scanned info column? As a sanity check, Scanned Info column should be identical to the Name column but scanned info is directly filled via QR code scans while for the sake or argument, other columns were manually entered.

Would be nice to be able to use a regular android phone to scan the QR code (i.e. not bound any special apps) and get the data embedded in the form (in a specific column here- Scanned Info column). This spreadsheet is a Google Spreadsheet i.e., an online document and should be updated as and when the QR codes are scanned.

Additional challenge being, how do we select which row of the Scanned Info columns to place the information so that the column remains in the same order as the Name column (which is not arranged alphabetically).

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search and research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Are you the only one going to use this? The issue is G-Suite APIs rquire authentication so making any QR code to fetch data would require your API key which could be potentially extracted and is a security risk.

Comment: For the time being I am the only one who is going to use it. How would I go about do so?

Answer (score 0):

QR codes are just a type of machine-readable barcode containing information, and by using one alone it isn't possible to run a script or program.

Most QR readers will automatically open a web browser when a QR code containing a URL is scanned, which is the extent you're really able to do though. You can use this to your advantage to build a workaround to grap the data you're looking for.

You can set up a `php` server-side script which can take `?` parameters in URLs for the cell or cell range you want to be able to read. The script should be designed to take in a range in A1 notation (for example `www.someexampledomain.com/page.php?range=a1`). Taking this range, you can follow the [PHP Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) to connect to the Google Sheets API and fetch values of cells or ranges of cells based on the `?` parameters you passed in the URL. For example if you passed something like `?range=a1` in the URL you could take the parameter and call

```php
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

Where `$range` is the range passed via URL. You can find the reference for Google spreadsheets [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets), and the value for setting and gettinv cell values [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values).

The PHP page can then generate HTML content which is returned as the response to the request which will be viewed in the browser that is opened by the URL in the QR code. Each QR code will have to be generated to have the cell range in the URL so that the PHP script can fetch the relevant information.

This is just a simple step-by-step guide for a way to achieve this, but this is just one of a few ways you could potentially achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want Google Apps Script (GAS) to read a QR code from camera then input that data to a specified range.

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73117564/is-it-possible-to-scan-a-qr-code-with-google-app-script) answers that question.

---

The workaround that I use is combining my iPhone camera (iOS 16.7) with Google Sheets Mobile App. It's not automated but no coding required. Though you [could automate the process](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250536998) with Shortcuts app.

__  I open Camera, scan the QR code, copy to clipboard (tap southeast corner of Camera when hovering over QR code), navigate to target cell in gSheets Mobile, and paste.

__ I only use gSheets Mobile as a landing pad, to paste the data in gSheets. I use gSheets Desktop for everything else. Once you get the data in gSheets you can deploy scripts to send it to parent table or whatever.