# Image function does not generate QR Code . How to obtain data from qr code generate url?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, crud, qr-code

**The goal** is to update row items by grabbing a unique itemID number for each item's qr code url (generated by a qr code IMAGE function).

**Problem:** This does not generate a QR code and infact does not even give an error in google sheets: `=image("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data=" &ENCODEURL("https://script.google.com/..../dev?v=update&itemID=123"))`

How do I get that *123* in the encoded url?

**Additional Context to my Question:**

I already have a working web app that interacts with google sheets database and allows users to update specific cell items by searching the database. I am essentially automating by upgrading by rather than making user search 1000 items, they just scan a QR code for that particular item.

I believe that the next step would be to skip encoded characters and use query parameters. I could then pass the parameters to any function as needed. Essentially I have figured out Step 2 before Step 1.

**Possible Unclear Solution**
I also looked into qrcode generator API but did not get information on how to add any additional data like itemID to a QR code except for data & size. Is the only way to do it by encoding the itemID by using &itemID=123 then? I have also researched this link already: [Is there a simple script one could you to scan QR code data and directly enter data the information into a specific column of the Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085364/is-there-a-simple-script-one-could-you-to-scan-qr-code-data-and-directly-enter-d)

I appreciate the folks here for constant help and guidance.

Comment: Try different image modes: `=image(...., 1or2or3)`. Enlarge your row. Adjust formatting. Wait...

Comment: I think it was glitching. I had to put the link in a separate cell and do a  Encode(URL) and add it to &data= . Thank you!